# Why am I getting list index error in quicksort algortihm. Can anyone review it please

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, quicksort

I am working on the quicksort algorithm with first element as the pivot. Below is the code that I have written for the program. I am getting the error List index out of range error in line lst[k]>=piv. Where am I going wrong.

```
def partition(lst,low,high):
piv=lst[low]
i=low+1
k=high-1
while i<=k:
    while lst[i]<=piv:
        i=i+1

    while lst[k]>=piv:
        k=k-1
    if i<=k:
        lst[i],lst[k]=lst[k],lst[i]
    else:
        lst[low],lst[k]=lst[k],lst[low]
return k

def quicksort(lst,low,high):
    if high-low>1:
        p=partition(lst,low,high)
        quicksort(lst,low,p)
        quicksort(lst,p+1,high)
    return lst
```

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs so we can test it?

Comment: you can have list of random numbers, but below is the test case on which i was working.

a=[65,8,4,5,6,54,34,21,2,46,75,33,76,1]

Comment: What do you use as inputs for low and high? Because if high is larger than len(lst), it'll definitely give you an out of range error

Comment: My bad that I din't mention about the inputs for low and high. low= 0 and high=len(a)-1

Comment: If high is set to len(a)-1 then you shouldn't get the out of range error

Comment: Your inner loops in `partition` can both run off the ends of the array. Guard for that.

Comment: but I have mentioned i<=k condition in parent while loop which should prevent it from running out of bound right?

Comment: The outer check that you mention will prevent `while lst[i]<=piv: i=i+1` from being entered with `i > k`, but this loop itself can cause `i` to run over the value of `k`.